# How to have two bootstrap columns with the right one being boxed and the left one being full width from center to left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two divs next to eachother. I want the first div to be acting like it is inside 'container-fluid' so fill the width infinitely to the left (according to screen width/size) and the second div act like it is inside a normal container, so stop at the right at the container width.

How can I do this?

I only know how to make both of them full width of the page or both of them boxed inside a container. Not how to make the left full width and the right boxed. Can this be done?

```css
.divresellerleft {
  width: 40%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  position: relative;
}

.divresellerright {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 60%;
  height: 600px;
  padding-left: 140px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid bannernopadd">
  <div class="resellerblockwrap">
    <div class="divresellerleft">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="socialmedia">
    </div>
    
    <div class="divresellerright row">
      <div class="insidekopje">
        <h1>Snel verdiend</h1>
        
        <span>Bouw aan je merk. Groei met ons mee. Zo worden we samen sterk.</span>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need this layout because the left div has a background color that I always want to go all the way to the left of the screen.

Example image:
[image]

Comment: You have one container and one row, but no columns. Seems like you should have two rows and three columns (in total). You can also use two containers (one of each type). Please review the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/).

Comment: I'm a little confused by your requirements. You have one box with "full width of screen" on it, but you have something next to it. You also have two containers with limited width but of different sizes. Please revise to clarify.

Comment: @isherwood Yes I mean the left box needs to go infinitely to the left (according to screen size) and the box on the right never go outside the container. So basically have two columns inside a container of 1200px, the one on the right never go beyond that 1200px but the one on the left needs to reach full width to the left outside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.left-column {
            box-shadow: -100vw 0 0 100vw #212529;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <div class="overflow-hidden">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 bg-dark text-white py-3 left-column">Left</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 py-3 right-column">
                        <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please run code snippet with full-page mode.  And let me know do you need this type or the content of the left bar should start from beginning of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For this the parent should be a flex container with `display: flex;`.
Then the left child to be given `flex: 1;`.
Right child needs to have a fix width (can be in percentage)